# Could I call "mkdir" function with Google app engine for PHP SDK?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Could I call "mkdir" function with Google app engine for PHP SDK?

I have tried with the living GAE for PHP, seems failed to create the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create directory during runtime on GAE.

Take a look at the GAE's [introduction](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine). In the `The Sandbox` paragraph, it says:

> Applications cannot write to the file system in any of the runtime
>   environments. An application can read files, but only files uploaded
>   with the application code. The app must use the App Engine datastore,
>   memcache or other services for all data that persists between
>   requests.

I think that's why you failed to create the directory.

Comment: Thanks. But it's seems App Engine datastore for PHP is unavailable at this moment.

Comment: @JeffMorriss Perhaps you could try [Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/developers-guide)